# How can I style the active slide of slick.js using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

I want to style the **active** slide to have an orange border.

[image]

Knowing that that class is : `slick-active` and the structure look like this :

```
<div class='slick-slide slick-active' ...>
```

I come up with this :

**jQuery**

```
$('div').find('.slick-active').css('border', 'orange 3px solid');
```

I couldn't get them to display. Can someone help me with this ?

**Update:**

After fixing my jQuery syntax error, I got the border to display, but that not what I intentionally want.

Result as of now :

[image]

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/va5qkycp/12/)

Comment: dot is missing before css

Comment: `$('div').find('.slick-active').css('border', '3px solid orange');`

Comment: hmm... dang it. I'm very close.

Comment: @JqueryKing : Thanks. It highlight all 3 of slides. Any idea why ? See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/va5qkycp/12/). Are you familiar with [Slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Nothing i can make with single jquery line please share your event details

Comment: I update my post with screenshot of my result, and the link to my full-code. Thanks.

Comment: ok what you want now tell me?

Comment: .slick-active length is 3 so it apply for all the 3 divs. make it one active class

Comment: you said defaultly slidesToShow: 3, so .slick-active class apply for 3 div

Comment: Hmm... I intentionally want to highlight only one div. which is the one is selected in the begining, if I click on the right arrow, then the div the right will selected, and if I click the back arrow, the one on the left will highlighted, so on and so forth. ... I hope that helps.....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/va5qkycp/13/

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same problem until I found this: https://community.serif.com/forum/18904/how-do-i-add-the-slick-slider-to-webplus. Martin has a great answer that simply involves adding some css to the .slick-center class. Adding your orange border under the first code block should work!

```
.center .slick-center h3 {
    -moz-transform:scale(1.08);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.08);
    -o-transform:scale(1.08);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.08);
    color:#e67e22;
    opacity:1;
    transform:scale(1.08);
 }
.center h3 {
    opacity:0.8;
    transition:all 300ms ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

since i was facing the same problem and for further reference:

I was able to get this done with using the class **.slick-current**

I placed a div around it so i can usw the selector **#divID .slick-current {}**

example:

```
#sliderPreviewBox .slick-current  {
padding-bottom: 5px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #006ab2;
color: blue; 
}
```